# MVC 5 and CDN thoughts

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, cdn

I've begun some serious work on my startup's introductory site.  It will be written in MVC where most controllers only have an Index action and view and these will be static for relatively long periods of time, days, weeks, even months.

I've been away from development for a while firstly due to an incident where I ended up cracking the back of my head open and shortly after recovering from that I severely injured my left hand.  Until this week it had been in either a splint or a cast for 8 weeks and I still have to attend physio sessions and ... anyway I took a break from coding.

Prior I specialised in WCF and MVC but did a side project with Angular and MVC.  I hoped in my time away from coding that some clever group of people would have come up with a way of pre-compiling controllers which simply spit out a page and have no other purpose in life,  the Angular/SEO problem and anything else cool in these areas.

My question is do I simple code up a static .html page for these and tweaking the web.config to support it, has anyone come-up with an automated way to do it or would simply setting the output cache up correctly be the way forward?

I'm using CloudFlare as my CDN and really want these sites to be super fast.  This will, as is always the case, be a positive representation of your company and will help when I go to investor meetings etc.

I'd be grateful if you would share your thoughts on the above and hope I've explained myself clearly.

Thanks,
Lee.

Comment: On the server side, just add an OutputCache attribute to your controller actions.  As for your CDN, you can configure the pages to be cached for X length of time?  I'm pretty sure that cloudflare 'just works'?

Comment: Yes you can do that on the CDN.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to use Angular JS for your static pages?

Comment: At the moment no but take the one page that has some interaction hopefully on a frequent basis, a contact form.  There's no reason to post back to an action, you should just as easily send it to a Web API controller.  There will be two other sites that will be the online stores.  They don't come into this though other than to sat the main site really is just for marketing.  The Only functionality will be a contact form as said.  Also it could be plain jQuery used rather than Angular.

Comment: Indeed, but sending it back to an action is basically the same as sending it back to WebAPI.  In fact in the latest version of MVC it _is_ the same, they are unified.

Comment: Which is great because there's no traditional rendering involved.  I dunno, perhaps I have't worded this post well enough.  I'm just seeing if there is anything new out there that I've overlooked while catching up on things recently.